# How do I get Eclipse to 'see' my AVD?

Tags: android

I have created an AVD which is shown to be a valid one as denoted by the green check mark.

When I have to select a build target however, it doesn't show my AVD in the list for Build Target.

How do I get Eclipse to 'see' my AVD?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check your `AndroidManifest` file to see what you placed as `minSDK`. Eclipse will not show a AVD with lower SDK than the one mentioned on the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

Your AVD won't show in the list of Build Targets. It'll try to appear the first time you compile and run.

Then, if you have more than one AVD that fits the target specifications, you'll get a dialog asking which one you want to use. Otherwise, it'll open your AVD, no questions asked.